# Summarizing Attributes in ArcGIS Online

Tags: arcgis-online, statistics

I need to find a way to summarize an attribute in ArcGIS Online. I know it is a simple task in ArcGIS Pro where one just needs to look check the statistics and look at the properties section. However, I cannot find a way to do this analysis in ArcGIS Online.

How do I find the sum of the square footage for all entries while in an ArcGIS Online web app?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could look at the [Summary](https://doc.arcgis.com/en/web-appbuilder/create-apps/widget-summary.htm) widget.

It is simple enough to configure, just choose the field you want to summarise and define the summary method.

[image]

You can of course alter the name of the widget/set labels for each summary so they are clear.

[image]